# Iterar um objeto dentro de outro. É possível?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
let myObject = {
        nome: 'Nome',
        idade: 20,
        endereco: {
            rua: 'Tal',
            numero: 5,
            municipio: {
                codigo: 1,
                ibge: '001'
            }
        }
    };

    Object.keys(myObject)
      .forEach((key) => {
         console.log(key);
         // 'nome', 'idade', 'endereco'
      });
```

Quero poder fazer com que determinado método, receba um objeto e consiga iterar todos as propriedades, mesmo que sejam encadeadas. É possível?

Comment: Oi Vitor, podes traduzir a pergunta para português? Queres iterar propriedades internas recursivamente, é isso? qual é a aplicação que queres alcançar?

Comment: Isso, Sérgio. Basicamente isso, quero que um possível método receba um objeto e seja capaz de identificar todos os valores das propriedades, mesmo que a propriedade análise carregue outro objeto, entende? Acabei mandando em inglês sem notar que tava na página português. Foi mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se a propriedade é um objeto com `prop instanceof Object` ou `typeof prop === 'object'`, se for, use recursividade para iterar sobre as propriedades desse objeto também.

```js
let myObject = {
    nome: 'Nome',
    idade: 20,
    endereco: {
        rua: 'Tal',
        numero: 5,
        municipio: {
            codigo: 1,
            ibge: '001'
        }
    }
};

function iterar(obj) {
    for (let prop in obj) {
        console.log(prop);
        if (obj[prop] instanceof Object) {
            iterar(obj[prop]);
        }
    }
}

iterar(myObject);
```

Nota: arrays são considerados objetos em JavaScript, e também irão entrar na condição.

Comment: Obrigado! Essa alternativa fez exatamente o que eu precisava ..

Answer (score 1):

Tens de criar uma função que verifique se um dado objeto contem a chave que procuras e que caso tenha objetos (ou arrays) aninhados os percorra recursivamente chamando-se a si própria.

Uma sugestão seria:

```js
// Retorna null or object with `{value: xxx}`

const procuraChave = (obj, chave) => {
  const chaves = Object.keys(obj);

  if (chaves.includes(chave)) {
    return {value: obj[chave]};
  }
  
  for (let c of chaves) {
    if (typeof obj[c] === 'object') {
      return procuraChave(obj[c], chave);
    }
  }

  return null;
}

const teste = {
  produto: 'Meu produto',
  detalhes: {
    preco: {
      fabrico: 250,
      venda: 500
    }
  }
};

const precoVenda = procuraChave(teste, 'venda');
console.log('Preço de venda:', precoVenda);
```

Comment: Sergio, muito obrigado! Essa solução também me atende, quando preciso buscar algo específico dentro do objeto.